# Can I confirm that a message has been deleted at the receiving end?

Tags: messages

When I delete a just sent message in iOS Messages, can I confirm that it has also been deleted for the recipient (without, of course, asking them)?

I'm using macOS 14 and iOS 17, but I don't know how up to date the receiver is.

Comment: You can be sure by asking the receiver

Comment: @tama The receiver can lie or just be mistaken or find it on another device later.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot verify whether the message was deleted.

If you do not receive a message warning you that it may not have been deleted (because the recipient is on an older version of iOS/macOS) then it likely was deleted.

However, there is no way to guarantee deletion because the recipient might have more than one device (and one device might be offline, etc.), or the recipient might have saved the message in a screenshot.

Comment: Any idea what the thinking is behind the functionality (and for calling the command "Delete")? It strikes me as a very strange UX.

Comment: The functionality is “undo send” @orome. Where did you come up with delete? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201287 The verb “delete” is for cleaning up your message history (either locally or iCloud synced to your devices only) and doesn’t affect other recipients.

Comment: @bmike My mistake. So there's no undo on Sonoma, just iOS?

Comment: Sonoma also has undo send on right click of a message. Remember it only appears for a couple minutes after sending.